# TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY not rendering

Tags: opengl, go, textures, shader

I'm using golang with OpenGL.
I use TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY load texture render a cube, but it result is a black cube.
I'm sure the texture unit is specified correctly because when I use `ActiveTexture(gl.TEXTURE3)` in `TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` load mode, it's display purposes, but now use TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY look like texture doesn't work.

texture loading code like this

```
func GenBindTexture(TextureType uint32) uint32{

var texture uint32
gl.GenTextures(1, &texture)
gl.ActiveTexture(gl.TEXTURE3)
gl.BindTexture(TextureType, texture)
//gl.TexEnvi()

return  texture
}
func TestTextureArray(){
fmt.Println("texture number:",GenBindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY))
rgba,err:=DrawRGBA("Texture/T1.png")
if err!=nil{
    fmt.Println("Err:",err)
    return
}
gl.TextureStorage3D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
    1,
    gl.RGBA,
    int32(rgba.Rect.Size().X),int32(rgba.Rect.Size().Y),
    1,
)
fmt.Printf("error is invlid option:%x\n",gl.GetError())//in here get INVALID_ENUM

gl.TexSubImage3D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
    0,
    0,0,int32(0),
    int32(rgba.Rect.Size().X),int32(rgba.Rect.Size().Y),1,
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    gl.Ptr(rgba.Pix),//they are color,i'm not set for random ,just test
)
fmt.Printf("error is invlid option:%x\n",gl.GetError())//in here get INVALID_Value
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)//
}
```

render&uniform setting

```
    TestTextureArray()
textureUniform := gl.GetUniformLocation(program, gl.Str("tex1\x00"))
gl.Uniform1i(textureUniform, 3) //传输tex1为对应的纹理单元id ，如果tex1已经被binding=纹理单元id则不用如此操作
//gl.Uniform1i(0,0)

fmt.Printf("error is:%x\n",gl.GetError())
gl.ClearColor(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.6)

angle := 0.0
previousTime := glfw.GetTime()

for !window.ShouldClose() {
    gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    // Update
    time := glfw.GetTime()
    elapsed := time - previousTime
    previousTime = time

    angle += elapsed
    model = mgl32.HomogRotate3D(float32(angle), mgl32.Vec3{0, 1, 0})

    // Render
    gl.UseProgram(program)
    gl.UniformMatrix4fv(modelUniform, 1, false,&model[0])
    gl.BindVertexArray(vao)
    //gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6*4)
    Render(program)
    window.SwapBuffers()
    glfw.PollEvents()
}
}
func Render(program uint32){
for CubeFace:=0;CubeFace!=6;CubeFace++  {
    SetUniformVar(program,"Layer",CubeFace)
    //gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6*4)
gl.DrawElementsBaseVertex(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP,4,gl.UNSIGNED_INT,gl.PtrOffset(0),int32(CubeFace*4))
}
```

}

and shader code like this

```
var VertexShaderMulti=`
# version 450
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 camera;
uniform mat4 model;

in vec3 vert;
in vec2 vertTexCoord;

out vec2 uv;

void main() {
    uv = vertTexCoord;
    gl_Position = projection * camera * model * vec4(vert, 1.3);
}
` + "\x00"


var FragmentShaderMulti=`
# version 450

uniform sampler2DArray tex1;
uniform int Layer=2;

in vec2 uv;

out vec4 outputColor;

void main(void){
    outputColor=texture(tex1, vec3(uv,0));
    }
`+ "\x00"
```

Now i use RenderDoc find sampler2DArray tex1 value in fact
[sampler2DArray tex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15N03.png)
any help and I would be very grateful!

Comment: Bold font wont give your question more importance

Comment: so any idea?I've had an excruciating for this question all day QWQ

Comment: Don't include (or link to) photos of text. Just copy-and-paste the text instead.

Comment: okey but why ? i want vivid metaphor for this questioin

Comment: Where is the rendering code? Where do you set the texture uniform? Did you check with a GPU debugger whether the texture contains valid data?

Comment: i added rendering and texture uniform setting code,before  i did't put those code ,because  it no change in my using TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP those code works fine ,but i don't know how to debug shader program  in golang opengl, i 'dont know  texture value whether lawful in fact i never obseve on they running

Comment: but the image load and TexCoord it valid because they all works fine in TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP mode

Comment: @BDL so any idea?QWQ my vertexs and uv cooride works fine in  TEXTURE_2D but not on TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY mode

Comment: From what I see atm, you are calling `Uniform1i` before binding the correct shader (`UseProgram`). Uniforms can only be set when the corresponding shader is active.

Comment: @BDL yeah,i know that and i have two line write UseProgram,i delete that in loop

Comment: @BDL another one is under the compileShader,i did't put that code,i test uniforms number ,and when shader receive the number will rendering blue cube and i successful for that test,but it seem Uniform1i works fine,and when i just delete redundant of UseProgram in forloop ,it still result is black cube  so…… what's the problem?

Comment: @BDL now i use Gpudebugger RenderDoc find sampler2DArray tex1 value in fact,i added that picture in my post,so what's the next?

Answer (score 1):

finally i find the reason, using `gl.GetError()` after `gl.TextureStorage3D` i get `INVALID_ENUM` ,reference this [document](http://docs.gl/gl4/glTexStorage3D) that means internal format has problem,so i change `gl.RGBA` to `gl.RGBA8`

everything is working perfect~ it a has multi texture binding one texture unit a  [beautiful cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygoCO.png)~

thanks for every answerer,  i'm not alone ^v^